# How do I get the grid parent of my control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a control in a grid and would like to access the grid. I don't have access to the grid in the code behind but I do have access to an instance of the control. Is there a way to obtain the grid parent using the instance of the control?

Comment: Can't you use `(Grid)theControl.Parent`?

Comment: @dbaseman Yes, my problem was that Parent was null at the time that I first viewed it and thought I was doing something wrong. Type casting Control.Parent works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your control is a button within a Grid, and that you access to this Button via the clicking event, this is how you would access the Grid.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid x = (sender as Button).Parent as Grid;
}
```